# Setting same time interval for multiple days in the calendar using Intent

Tags: android

I'm currently using this code to add an event to a calendar in the user's device:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
    intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
    intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, mission.company.name);
    intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION, mission.service.address);
    intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, startCal.getTimeInMillis());
    intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, endCal.getTimeInMillis());
    intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.ALL_DAY, false);// periodicity
    intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION,
            function.name + "\n\n" + mission.service.address + "\n\n" + mission.service.phone
    );

    String title = "Choose the calendar you want to save the event to";
    Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, title);
    try {
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(chooser);
        }
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.toast_no_application_found_for_action), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

My problem is that this will only add ONE event. I have cases where in the same time interval (i.e. 12:00PM - 13:00PM) needs to repeat for 2-3 days (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday). How can I change the code (i want to use Intents) to accomplish this? If I just set the start of the event on Monday at 12:00PM and say it'll end on Wednesday on 13:00PM that's no good, as it'll set one long event.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Try to add one more thing to your Intent, an extra of CalendarContract.Events.RRULE with a value of "FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=3"(where 3 is the number of recurring event days).

Comment: Yeah, I was just implementing that myself. If you want, you can write that as an answer and i'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a new extra to your Intent to set the CalendarContract.Events.RRULE field to the value "FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=x"(where x is the number of days for the recurring event).